# Que tomar en cuenta para mostrar Unas publicaciones usando PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hola anterior mente ya había hecho una publicación similar, me ayudaron muy bien, pero siempre tengo el mismo problema.

Les explico tengo mi archivo `post_empresa.php`

ahí tengo el codigo para llamar los datos de la tabla `tb_post`.

```
<?php

 include '../AvisionV2/db/db.php';

 $query_sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_post LIMIT 2";

 if ($resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_sql)) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
      echo '<pre>';

      #print_r($row); 

      $titulo = $row["i_titulo"]; #lo mando a en mostrar_post.php
      $descripccion = $row["i_descripcion"]; 

      echo 'Su Titulo es : ' . $titulo; #solo es prueba
      echo '<pre>'; 
      echo 'Su descripcion es : ' . $descripccion; #solo es prueba
 }
      mysqli_free_result($resultado);
 }

 mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Y tengo otro archivo que se llama `mostrar_post.php`, donde se visualiza los post que tiene la tabla `tb_post`

Ahora aqui esta el archivo `mostrar_post.php`

```
<?php include '../AvisionV2/post_empresa.php'; ?>
<?php include '../AvisionV2/db/db.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
 </head>

 <body>

 <div>
      <h5>Titulo : <?php echo $titulo ?> </h5>
      <h5>Descripcion : <?php echo $descripccion ?> </h5>
      <h5>Producto : </h5>
      <h5>Usuario : </h5>
 </div>



 </body>

 </html>
```

En esta parte me tiene que mostrar las dos entradas que yo he limitado 
          `<h5>Titulo : <?php echo $titulo ?> </h5>
          <h5>Descripcion : <?php echo $descripccion ?> </h5>`

Entonces el resultado visual para el saurio seria

**Primera Publicación**

Titulo 1 
Descripción 1

**Segunda Publicación**

Titulo 2
Descripción 2

Pero cuando yo lo visualizo solo me imprime la ultima entrada limitada que seria

Titulo 2
Descripción 2

Imagen del resultado Final

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que tomar en cuenta para solucionar este error

espero su ayuda, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ronald.

Hay ciertas cosas a considerar. Te explico. Por lo que tengo entendido tú ocupas tu archivo `mostrar_post.php` para mostrar todos los registros traídos desde tu consulta previa `post_empresa.php`, ¿cierto?

El problema es que si de verdad quieres mostrar todos los registros recuperados desde tu tabla `tb_post` desde `post_empresa.php` vas a tener que poner una solución, te propongo tres:

1. Que desde `post_empresa.php` almacenes un `array` para guardar todos los post recuperados e iterarlos posteriormente en `mostrar_post.php`.
2. Que hagas la consulta dentro de `mostrar_post.php` en lugar de pasar primero por `post_empresa.php`
3. Que desde `post_empresa.php`concatenes en una variable todos los valores recuperados dentro de tu ciclo `while` **[RECOMIENDO ESTA PORQUE ES LA MÁS FÁCIL]**

Ahora bien, respondiendo por partes a las dudas que tienes, te comento:

1. Es normal que cuando veas el resultado final solamente veas una sola vez impreso tu `mostrar_post.php` porque realmente solo lo estás impremiendo una sola vez, así como también, desde un inicio en `post_empresa.php` en cada vuelta de tu `while` sobre escribiste el último valor tanto en `$titulo` como en `$descripcion`
2. Lo que yo tomaría en cuenta para solucionar el error que tienes y lo que estás esperando es usar la solución #3 que te mencioné; concatenar.

Ahora bien, poniendo manos a la obra y centrándonos en la parte de tu código dentro de `post_empresa.php` vamos a modificar ligeramente el ciclo while, concatenando (por favor visita este [enlace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php) para más información sobre cómo concatenar en php strings):

I. Usamos una variable auxiliar que llamaremos `$informacion`

II. A esta variable `$informacion` en cada vuelta le concatenamos los valores recuperados de tu consulta

III. Esta variable `$informacion` la vamos a usar dentro de `mostrar_post.php`

```
 $informacion = "";
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
      $informacion .=  '<pre>';

      #print_r($row); 

      $titulo = $row["i_titulo"]; #lo mando a en mostrar_post.php
      $descripccion = $row["i_descripcion"]; 

      $informacion .= 'Su Titulo es : ' . $titulo; #solo es prueba
      $informacion .=  '<pre>'; 
      $informacion .=  'Su descripcion es : ' . $descripccion; #solo es prueba
 }
```

Si te das cuenta, en lugar de imprimir los datos en el ciclo, los estamos concatenando, de tal forma que tengamos todo reunido en una sola variable al finalizar el ciclo.

Para finalizar, nos vamos a ir al archivo `mostrar_post.php`. Y como bien lo haces en tu código, con el hecho de incluir como lo haces `<?php include '../AvisionV2/post_empresa.php'; ?>` ya vas a tener disponible la variable `$informacion` y llena de datos.

Lo único que te toca hacer es imprimir esta variable en donde la necesites dentro de tu `mostrar_post.php` para obtener el resultado final que sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tu código final `mostrar_post.php` para ver los resultados quedaría así:

```
<?php include '../AvisionV2/post_empresa.php'; ?>
<?php include '../AvisionV2/db/db.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
 </head>

 <body>

 <?php echo $informacion; ?>


 </body>

 </html>
```